# How does one map a graph into a vector (feature space)?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Assuming there is an undirected weighted graph. How can one convey it's geometrical structure into a feature space? Are there any common practices?

Comment: are you familiar with the [incidence matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix)? (I don't really know what a 'feature' is, I hope this help you anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an embedding of nodes into low dimensional Euclidean space that approximates the original edge weights as Euclidean distances between the embedded nodes, so that e.g. you can visualize the graph where edge weights are basically distances, you can look up so-called multidimensional scaling.

Comment: I want an embedding like that, however one of my requirements would be to have at least some visual distinction between dense regions of the graph, in other words I want to see parts of the graph which are more closely coupled and which are less closely coupled. Do you think MDS can do it?

Comment: @DenysS. MDS should do this if your different "dense" regions each have points that are all close together, whereas the distance in between different dense regions is much larger. But if you have many points where there's a number of "sparsely spread" points in between dense regions, it may be hard to see. I'd recommend creating a heat map by dividing up MDS plot into small equal sized squares and then the color for a square is determined by the percentage of points in the square (e.g. max = bright green, average = black, and min = bright red, depending on what heat map palette you use).

Comment: MDS worked well, checking out Isomap. Thanks!